# Static link an existing windows binary

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I was wondering if I can take an existing windows DLL and static link the dynamically-linked files?

I saw a number of projects to do this with Linux/elf
http://magicermine.com/
http://statifier.sourceforge.net/
http://bitwagon.com/jumpstart/jumpstart.html

I imagine this is most likely not possible, but I am running into some issues in WinPE where when I statically linked the DLLs everything started working great.

I don't have the source to the existing DLL.

I guess I could make a pass-through DLL that exposed all of the same functions and static linked?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool support for linking in the code of a DLL statically.

The problem is that a DLL is a full Windows PE executable, not a C or C++ “library” in any sense. The C++ standard has only one statement that is vaguely in support of DLL-like things (in the para about dynamic initialization after first statement of `main`). You’re out of luck.

But if you had the source code (as e.g. with MFC), which you say you don’t, then you could just have created static libraries.

---

Do note that there already *is* a meaning for “linking statically” a DLL, namely to have it loaded and have its functions resolved automatically.

Which is the usual way of using a DLL.

And which is in contrast to explicitly loading it dynamically and using `GetProcAddress` to resolve its functions.

---

Regarding

> **”** when I statically linked the DLLs everything started working great

presumably earlier you have explictly loaded the DLLs dynamically, and used `GetProcAddress`, and presumably something about that did not work perfectly.

One main problem with `GetProcAddress` is that it assumes that the provided function name is encoded as Windows ANSI (the machine-dependent encoding reported by `GetACP`), and then (apparently) translates that to UTF-8 for the function lookup.

One workaround could be to access the function by ordinal rather than name.

One way to find the ordinal with Microsoft's tools, is to use `dumpbin /exports`.